# Right align Boostrap's media-heading class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Has anyone been able to successfully right align Bootstrap's media-heading class? Swapping or adding pull-right doesn't work

```
    <div class="media">

      <div class="media-body">
      <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="media-right">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="media-object" src="..." alt="...">
        </a>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: My code sample just shows the media-object right aligned but the goal is to be able to right align the heading within media-body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give `text-right` class to `media-body`

```
<div class="media">
   <div class="media-body text-right">
     <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>
     ...
   </div>
   <div class="media-right">
     <a href="#">
       <img class="media-object" src="..." alt="...">
     </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That'll move everything contained in the div to the right if it isn't already. Should he only want the media-heading to be moved, he'd want to add that text-right class to the h4 element only.

Comment: I also think he just want on media-heading, but if just media heading aligned right, I think it will looks strange.

Comment: Thank you all! text-right did the trick on the header h4. The image on the right is quite large so it actually looks quite nice to just have the header be right aligned and the english text is easier to read when left-aligned.